# WP's white screen of death while opening the WP-Admin AND the website's pages with local

Tags: wordpress, localhost, local, staging

I have a white screen of death while intending to open the WP-Admin and my website's pages in local by flywheel.

In the admin > preferences > general of local, I changed the WP's url and the website's url from something like http://localhost:10010 to http://mywebsite.local. I also put this code in the wp-config.php file :

define('WP_HOME','http://mywebsite.local');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://mywebsite.local');

... and I have a beautiful white screen of death. I emptied my browser's cache... nothing changed.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance